# Use Dialog as navigation destination with jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

A dialog can have a rather complex ui, acting more like a floating screen rather than a typical AlertDialog. Therefore it can be desired to let the dialog have its own `ViewModel` and being able to navigate to it. When using the jetpack compose navigation artifact the code indicates that only one composable is shown at any time inside the `NavHost`.

Is there a way to navigate to a dialog that is overlaid onto the current ui? This would be in line with how we can navigate to fragment dialogs. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Aha. This is now a feature in compose navigation version 2.4.0-alpha04

From the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha04)

> The NavHost of the navigation-compose artifact now supports dialog
> destinations in addition to composable destinations. These dialog
> destinations will each be shown within a Composable Dialog, floating
> above the current composable destination.

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
Scaffold { innerPadding ->
    NavHost(navController, "home", Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
        composable("home") {
            // This content fills the area provided to the NavHost
            HomeScreen()
        }
        dialog("detail_dialog") {
            // This content will be automatically added to a Dialog() composable
            // and appear above the HomeScreen or other composable destinations
            DetailDialogContent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about bottom sheet dialogue

Comment: How do you dismiss that dialog inside DetailDialogContent() block

Comment: To dismiss that dialog you can use navController.popBackStack()

Answer (score 2):

Example:

[image]

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Screen.Menu.route
) {
    // some other screens here: composable(...) { ... }
    dialog(
        route = "exit_dialog",
        dialogProperties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = true,
            dismissOnClickOutside = true,
        )
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.width(280.dp)) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .background(DialogBorder)
                    .padding(bottom = 3.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .background(DialogBackground),
            ) {
                Column {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.text_dialog_exit_title),
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.text_dialog_exit_description),
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                    }
                    Divider(color = DialogBorder)
                    Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .clickable {
                                    // dismiss dialog
                                    navController.popBackStack()
                                }
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = stringResource(id = R.string.button_cancel),
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                color = Color.Black
                            )
                        }
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .width(1.dp)
                                .background(DialogBorder),
                        )
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .clickable {
                                    // go back to home other screen
                                    navController.popBackStack(
                                        route = "home_screen",
                                        inclusive = false
                                    )
                                }
                                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = stringResource(id = R.string.button_ok),
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
                                color = Color.Black
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179608120
You can star it so perhaps we'll increase it's priority

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/compose/package-summary#(androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder).dialog(kotlin.String,kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.collections.List,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function1)) from May 2023 there are 2 different use cases for displaying dialogs:

1. Use Compose navigation [dialog()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/compose/package-summary#(androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder).dialog(kotlin.String,kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.collections.List,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function1)) if dialog represents a separate screen in your app that needs its own lifecycle and saved state, independent of any other destination in your navigation graph
2. For use cases such as AlertDialog, you should use [Dialog()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Dialog(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function0)) composable directly in the composable destination that wants to show that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog in navigation like below

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.mainNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = AppScreen.Main.Home.route,
        route = AppScreen.Main.route
    ) {
        composable(route = AppScreen.Main.Home.route) {

            HomeScreen()
        }

        dialog(route = AppScreen.Main.ProductDetail.route) {  
   
            ProductDetail()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to make it full-screen,

```
    <style name="Theme.DialogFullScreen" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Main application Light Theme. -->
   <style name="Theme.FireflyCompose" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.DialogFullScreen</item>
    </style>
```